# Shadow of UICollectionView Cell suddenly disappears when the cell is about to go offscreen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with rounded and shadow-dropped cells. The shadow of the cell suddenly disappears, instead of smoothly moving out of the view, when the cell is about to be covered by the navigation bar. Below is the code:

```
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5.0)
    layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: contentView.layer.cornerRadius - 3).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Here is the gif showing the problem. Focus on the shadow at the bottom of the cell. The navigation bar is white. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

[image: Problem demonstration (gif)]

Comment: are you doing anything with collectionview's contentinset property?

Comment: I think as @Milan Nosáľ that it's because the cell disappear. A quick solution (might work, I don't know) would be to the allow the UICollectionView (through `NSLayoutConstraints`) to be under the Navigation Bar and letting it have a small "invisible cell" at first.

Comment: @user3808183 were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi Milan, thank you for the response, I am pretty sure it should work, since setting the Navigation Bar translucent solves the problem. But @Larme solution seems a little cleaner to me. Larme, do you mind going into a little more detail of how to extend Collection View below the Nav Bar? My collection view controller is the child of a parent controller embedded in the Navigation controller.

Comment: it's a question of the layout, you just have to make the collectionView top go under the navigationBar, but that depends on how you do the layout - without code its hard to suggest anything..

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's simply because the cell does really get removed from the view, thus it's shadow goes with it. At that point the frame of the cell is out of the view, while shadow is still visible (shadow is around the frame) - but when the frame goes out of view, the `collectionView` removes the cell. And so the shadow disappears abruptly.

What I would do about it is very simple. I would refactor the code to wrap the current cell contents into a new `UIView` - lets call it `wrapper`, that will drop the shadow. Then put this `wrapper` into the cell's `contentView` so that the `wrapper` along with its shadow will fit inside of the `contentView`. Then the shadow will become a part of the `contentView` frame, which means that the shadow will disappear from the screen only when the whole cell is hidden.

Of course, you will have to modify the `collectionView`'s size for cell, because now the cells will be bigger to contain also the shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting shadow of `contentView` embed all your content in a `UIView` and set shadow of that view instead. Then you have to increase the height of your cell about `20 points` or as much your shadow height. That should work I guess.

Comment: why would you just basically repeat my answer?

Comment: Oh I didn’t see that or maybe we answered at same time. Do you have copyrights for your thoughts? I have answered in different way by the way 